# ruby - simplify string multiply concatenation

Tags: ruby, string-concatenation

s is a string, This seems very long-winded - how can i simplify this? :

```
   if x === 2
      z = s
    elsif x === 3
      z = s+s
    elsif x === 4
      z = s+s+s
    elsif x === 5
      z = s+s+s+s
    elsif x === 6
      z = s+s+s+s+s
```

Thanks

Comment: may be typo but === must be ==

Comment: @Salil: Works just fine with `===`. Though using `===` here is indeed quite unusual and possibly symptomatic of a misunderstanding of what `===` is for.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Something like this is the simplest and works ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Juvs6)):

```
puts 'Hello' * 3   # HelloHelloHello
 
s = 'Go'
x = 4
z = s * (x - 1)
puts z             # GoGoGo
```

#### API links

> [ruby-doc.org - `String`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000769): `str * integer => new_str`
>
> Copy—Returns a new `String` containing *integer* copies of the receiver.
>
> ```
> "Ho! " * 3   #=> "Ho! Ho! Ho! "
> ```

Comment: where has ideone.com been all my life +1

Answer (score 2):

```
z=''
(x-1).times do
 z+=s
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo code (not ruby)

```
if 1 < int(x) < 7  then
   z = (x-1)*s
```

Answer (score 1):

For example for a rating system up to 5 stars you can use something like this:

```
def rating_to_star(rating)
   'star' * rating.to_i + 'empty_star' * (5 - rating.to_i)
end
```