# String can't be coerced into Fixnum (trying to create padding of spaces)

Tags: ruby

I dont understand why I get the following error:

```
irb(main):001:0> spaces = " "
=> " "
irb(main):002:0> multiplied_spaces = 5 * spaces
TypeError: String can't be coerced into Fixnum
    from (irb):2:in `*'
    from (irb):2
    from /usr/local/opt/ruby@2.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):003:0>
```

spaces represents a string, and from what I can see in many other questions here is one [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3179198/5006720), this should work

What am I doing differently?

Comment: "What am I doing differently?" - order of the operands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just reverse the sequence of `' '` and `5` it will work.

```
spaces = " "
multiplied_spaces = spaces * 5
=> "     "
```